# Is there a Google Doc-style UML tool?

Tags: uml, collaboration

I’m looking for a collaborative UML-compliant tool. I work in the context of two geographically spread out teams and we need to work together on the designed models.

Is there a web-based UML modeling tool with model sharing?

Answer (score 55):

Well,

You can check those tools

- http://creately.com/
- https://sketchboard.me
- https://nulab-inc.com/products/cacoo/
- https://www.draw.io/ (free, [open source](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio), with [Desktop version](https://download.draw.io/))

Comment: draw.io is an excellent tool! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: All those tools are great, but do not create UML-compliant models/diagrams. All you get is a drawing, you can't be certain it conforms UML2 standard (metamodel)

Comment: UML is based on [ usefull when ]  commucating ideas, sharing same vocabulary to discover problem and solution space as a team. Unless you do not want to MDA or some sort of Executable UML [ both which are problematic and not mature ] or try to write a UML tool, ne need to worry about UML metamodel...

Comment: Cacoo link is broken. It's not hard to go back to its home page and compare it with the others, but whatever specific page you wanted to link to is apparently gone now.

Comment: @HippiasMinor It sounds like you've had experience with the metamodel - based on your comment on it being problematic and not mature. I couldn't agree more. I got OCUP UML cert because I had such high hopes. Spent a lot of time looking at dead ends at the time. Mostly in search for tools that could represent a large portion of an existing program. But I also looked at tools that might build out a good object hierarchy based on the DMTF's CIM. If anyone knows of any work/progress done in this area then I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Thx for sharing these tools - one issue though - all these are really just drawing tools with UML symbol template.  They are not true modelling tool (like ArgoUML, even old Rational Rose) where you can rename a method/attribute in the class diagram, it will automatically reflected in all sequence diagrams that use the method.  Does anyone any tool can do that and integrate with google docs like draw.io?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you, Hippias Minor and Xaelis for tools. I've tried GenMyModel, draw.io and Cacoo. Below goes table with their some of their benefits, I've found.

<kbd>GenMyModel</kbd>                                         <kbd>draw.io</kbd>                    <kbd>cacoo</kbd>

<kbd>save</kbd>            <kbd>auto</kbd>                                                        <kbd>dropbox, drive, disk</kbd><kbd>ctrl+s</kbd>

<kbd>features free</kbd><kbd>only public diagrams, 20 elements max</kbd><kbd>all</kbd>                            <kbd>25 sheets max</kbd>

<kbd>export</kbd>          <kbd>jpg, uml (xmi), pdf</kbd>                                  <kbd>png, jpg, pdf, html</kbd>   <kbd>png, pdf, ppt, vector</kbd>

<kbd>multiplayer :)</kbd>                              <kbd>+</kbd>                              <kbd>drive.draw.io</kbd>           <kbd>+</kbd>

Note, that cacoo and GenMyModel allows to edit diagram for many user simultaneosly, so one see changes right after other done them (drag finish will be seen). To collaborate with draw.io tool use drive.draw.io, but you have to register in google drive account (it shares link with that).

Now, I'm looking for something to show my cursor for others (like teacher has it's pointer) The only thing, I've already found is to add some geometry, e.g. rectangle and move it like pointer, but it's ugly. Will be glad for comments on that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a real (UML conformance validation, XMI export) web-based UML modeling tool, you should give a try to [GenMyModel](https://www.genmymodel.com/)

Comment: GenMyModels provides a Google Doc-style collaboration enabling to edit UML diagrams in real time together.